# CloudFormation and PowerShell: Template format error: unsupported structure with

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I cannot get any CloudFormation template to deploy or validate when using PowerShell, but using the exact template I have no issues doing it using AWS CLI or using the AWS Console.

Let's take a basic CloudFormation template, lets call it `Test.template`.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "Simple template.",
  "Parameters" : {    
    "KeyName" : {
      "Type" : "String", 
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the web server"
    }
  }, 

  "Resources" : {
    "Ec2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance", 
      "Properties" : {        
        "KeyName" : "test",        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing special, very basic. Ignoring that this would fail when you were to create the EC2 resource, this is a properly formatted JSON CloudFormation template.

Now, if I run this command using the AWS CLI, it comes back successful and outputs the paramaters:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://c:/temp/Test.template
```

Using the exact same file, if I run this in PowerShell I get an error:

```
Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody file://c:/temp/Test.template
```

> Test-CFNTemplate : Template format error: unsupported structure. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody file://c:/temp/Test.template
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...NTemplateCmdlet:TestCFNTemplateCmdlet)
>   [Test-CFNTemplate], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.CloudFormation.AmazonCloudFormationException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.CFN.TestCFNTemplateCmdlet

I also have no issues deploying this template using either the AWS Console or using `aws cloudformation create-stack` I just cannot figure out why I can't do it using PowerShell.

`New-CFNStack` is returning the same error above as well:

> Template format error: unsupported structure.

I installed the latest version of the AWS PowerShell module and I'm running Powershell 5.1.14409.1012

Everything else I found regarding this error were from folks who had issues because they weren't using `file://` in the TemplateBody but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `-TemplateBody` does not support local file URI.  You first need to read the template into a variable, and use that like below.

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\test.template")
Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody $content
```

After doing that, it will now give you the expected output.

```
Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody $content

Capabilities       : {}
CapabilitiesReason : 
DeclaredTransforms : {}
Description        : Simple template.
Parameters         : {KeyName}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too bad that -TemplateBody doesn't support local file URI. Luckily you can still specific they file inline.

```
Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody (get-content c:\test.template -Raw)
```

The command should return the expected result.

```
Test-CFNTemplate -TemplateBody (get-content c:\test.template -Raw)

Capabilities       : {}
CapabilitiesReason : 
DeclaredTransforms : {}
Description        : Simple template.
Parameters         : {KeyName}
```

I can't claim this is my solution as I did read it from this blog: https://matthewdavis111.com/aws/test-cloudformation-powershell/